# deploying laravel 8 app on heroku: api routes not working

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, heroku, deployment, routes

After i deployed my laravel 8 app on heroku, api routes are not working except for the index page
Locally everything works fine but on heroku only the index.php page works fine
[image: Procfile]

[image: .htaccess file]

what should i do ?

Comment: Kindly do add your htaccess Rule file in your question in text form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you guysfor your help
i solved the problem
it turned that i need to edit the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```